# How to find second-order partial derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Please, explain to me as you can how to find first-order and second-order derivatives for this function. It would be really helpful! Here is the function:

z=cot(y/x)

Seems like my solution isn't right and I can't do it right.

[I started, but didn't continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E8dt.jpg)

The 2 second-order derivatives seems like should be equal.

Comment: So what _is_ your solution?

Comment: Updated the question. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E8dt.jpg

Comment: Partial derivative with respect to *what*?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. At least the derivative with respect to $x$ looks correct to me.

Comment: What about derivative with respect to y? It equals to 0 with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first order partial derivatives, you have the equations

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{-y}{\sin^2 \left(\frac{y}{x}\right) x^2 }$$

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{-1}{\sin^2 \left(\frac{y}{x}\right) x} $$

by computation similar to what you have. Notice that you do *not* need the quotient rule for $\frac{y}{x}$ because either one of $y, x$ is a constant.

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I make second order partial derivatives based on the first order derivatives?

Comment: @DmitriiDronov I would recommend using the "reciprocal rule", that is, $\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{-f^\prime}{(f(x))^2}$.

Comment: The $z$ should be a $x$, sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW, Can I take a look at step-by-step solution?

Comment: @DmitriiDronov Why not use https://www.symbolab.com/ ?